# Testing for 'null' vs. testing for 'default(T)'

Tags: c#, linq

When I started using LINQ one of the samples I copied used this pattern, which I have been using ever since. Here's an example from a recent bit of code:

```
var heartbeat = db.HeartBeats.Where(hb => hb.macHash == macAddressHash).FirstOrDefault();
if (heartbeat != default(HeartBeat))
{
    result = heartbeat;
}
```

A few colleagues have expressed surprise at comparing the result of the LINQ query to `default(T)` rather than `null`.

Is there an advantage?

Comment: I've marked [Christos's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26649990/575530) as the answer but it is worth scrolling through the comments there to read @hvd's comment on anonymous types. I often use them in LINQ and for them writing `default(T)` is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FirstOrDefault` returns `null`, if the type you are looking for is a reference type and your query hasn't any results. So there isn't any reason of using the `default`.

However, I don't think that there is any advantage of using one another. The only good thing I can think is that using `null` is more expressive than `default(HeartBeat)`. I say so, because when we use the `default`, at first we read the expression `default(HeartBeat)`and then we recall that the default type of a reference type is `null`. While, using `null`, you avoid that milliseconds of thought.

**update**

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) about `FirstOrDefault`, we have that the signature of this method is the following:

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

and as it is stated there:

> Returns the first element of a sequence, *or a default value if the*
>   *sequence **contains no** elements*.

Or in other words returns

`default(TSource)` if source is empty.

Otherwise the first element in source.

Take into account the above, it is more close to the documentation to make use of `default(T)`, where `T` is your type in your if statements.

However, I prefer using the default value, `null`, `0`, `false` etc. rather than `default(T)`. This doesn't mean in no way that's the correct approach. It's a personal opinion. You pick.

Comment: Thanks Christos - I think readability may be the key. I'll swap to using a `null` comparison.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault<T>()` doesn't return `null` if the enumeration has no items, it returns `default(T)`, which may or may not be `null` depending on the concrete `T`.

Comment: @hvd that's the reason I mentioned above the if we are looking for a reference type is null. If you have an empty sequence of a reference type, then `FirstOrDefault` will return `null`. Isn't that correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Christos But if the specification of `FirstOrDefault<T>` is that it returns `default(T)` if the enumeration holds no items, and you compare to `default(T)`, you don't need to think about whether that is `null`. Following your logic should lead to the opposite conclusion.

Comment: So, @hvd, do you prefer the comparison to `default(T)`?

Comment: @dumbledad I find comparisons to `default(T)` and to `null` equally readable, but tend to compare to `null` personally for reference types, but for a different reason: I tend to not use enumerables of non-nullable value types anyway, and `null` works for all reference types (as well as nullable value types), not just the types that have a name. (`var y = x.Select(i => new { }).FirstOrDefault(); if (y != <...>) { ... }`: what can you place at the `<...>`?)

Comment: @hvd that is a very good point, I was forgetting anonymous types, clearly I cannot use `default(T)` when I do not know how to write `T`. If you write that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @dumbledad I'm glad it helped, but just that would be an incomplete answer, and posting a complete answer requires more time than I have available right now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Advantage: no. Difference: yes.

If you use for example `int`, the `FirstOrDefault` will return `0` as default. Comparing to `null` is useless, comparing to `default(T)` isn't.

In the case of `null`, the expression will result to `false`, in the case of `default(T)` it results to `true`.

In this case, if `HeartBeat` is a reference type, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @dumbledad: Need more help?

Comment: Thanks for your help Patrick - I'm good. I've marked Christos's as the answer (his was the first I read and @hxd's comment there on anonymous types is interesting). I tend to hang on for a day before marking an answer as the answer just-in-case.

Answer (score 1):

No difference here, obviously. I suppose it would make an impact when you change it to a collection of value types in the future but

1) This isn't all that common in my experience.

2) It would mean that your collection can't contain 0 although it might very well be a legitimate value.

Personally I find `!= null` more comfortable to read.